# Way to remove reversed key:value pairs in python map dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I've look around pretty extensively and I'm either overlooking something or I haven't been able to find a solution for it. Usually I'd avoid making a post but I've been trying to figure this out for nearly two days now.

I'm still somewhat new to python so I may be overlooking something here:

I have this Dict:

```
dict = {'27': 28, '28': 27, '30' : 31, '31' : 30}
```

I want to remove duplicate keys:values reversed.

So for the final dict I would like:

```
dict = {'27': 28, '30' : 31}
```

So have at least one key:value pair for each duplicate.

I apologize if this is a duplicate post, but I have looked all around for an answer but haven't found anything of use or that I can wrap my head around.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not good to overwrite python builtins...

Comment: Do you have to keep the first occurrence, in order? That is, would `{'28': 27}` be an acceptable result?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, just need duplicates removed.

Comment: why are the keys strings instead of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple keys:

```
data = {'27': 28, '28': 27, '30' : 31, '31' : 30}

seen = set()
seen_add = seen.update

data = {key: v for key, v in data.items() if not (((k := int(key)), v) in seen or seen_add(((k, v), (v, k))))}
```

---

```
{'27': 28, '30': 31}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Is there a way to do this for all keys?

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: It seems to work but is there a way to loop through the existing keys and append to the remove list? It seems when I loop through the dict it appends all the keys, which leaves me with an empty dict in the end.

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean?

Comment: Your updated response works, thanks so much for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a strict order (origin pair / inverted pair etc) in the dict, you can use this:

```
data = {'27': 28, '28': 27, '30' : 31, '31' : 30}

l1 = list(data.items())[0::2]
dict(l1)

# {'27': 28, '30': 31}
```